# NSNumber is getting rewritten to a memory pointer after being instantiated. [ xcode ]

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsnumber

I instantiate my NSNumber for easy handling later .

```
self.chatGroupId = ((NSNumber*)[params valueForKey: @"groupId"]);
```

Where this... `((NSNumber*)[params valueForKey: @"groupId"])`

returns :

```
ee8ff445ab814be487326145d4fd5238
```

However, a few methods later, when I want to draw this value, it returns as this :

```
(lldb) po self.chatGroupId
0x0000608000c7b8c0
```

Any idea why?

My `.h` file is this :

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSNumber * chatGroupId;
```

Comment: `@property (nonatomic, assign) NSNumber * chatGroupId;` => `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber * chatGroupId;` Also `ee8ff445ab814be487326145d4fd5238`, I'm not sure at all it's a `NSNumber`. Please, check `[[params valueForKey: @"groupId"] class]`, seems to be string (like an UUID).

Comment: @Larme Ah interesting, thanks so much for sharing friend. That was an absolute answer for me. Thank you.